# View twiml that was generated using Twilio functions

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

Is there any way to view the twiml that was generated using Twilio functions?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are using a Twilio Function to return TwiML during call and message flows then you can see the responses within your call and message logs.

For example, if you go to [your messaging logs](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/logs), click on a message and scroll to the bottom and you will see the "Request inspector". This shows all the requests and responses, including the TwiML that came back, whether it was from a Twilio Function or another URL.

Let me know if that helps at all.